# Import Office Interop as type "COM" instead of ".NET"

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

A new .net v.4.7.2 project when adding a reference to Microsoft Word 16 Object Library, it becomes added with type ".NET".
[image]

How to add it, type "COM"? In an old project flying around, it is referenced like this:
[image]

Both projects reference the same .dll, though. How to get it imported / referenced as COM ?

Comment: the interop dlls are for COM interop.

Comment: Both cases they the reference is added the same way in "COM" section.

Comment: I recommend changing your code to late-binding before publish. That way you aren't locked to a specific version of Word and you don't need the reference